# Delete special characters and symbols from my exported Excel in Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have this method for exporting an excel doc, but when I open the excel I get this kind of file with weird characters and symbols, no formatting; can someone guide me how to fix this?

[image]

This is my method, thanks for the help; I am still working on this.

```
 public void CrearExcel() throws SQLException {
        //Map param = new HashMap();


        try {
            Connection conn = Conexion.getConnTest();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String sql =
                "SELECT NUM_FICHA, ASPIRANTE.AP_PATERNO, ASPIRANTE.AP_MATERNO, ASPIRANTE.NOMBRE FROM REFERENCIA INNER JOIN ASPIRANTE ON REFERENCIA.FK_ASPIRANTE_ID_ASPIRANTE = ASPIRANTE.ID_USUARIO WHERE NUM_FICHA IS NOT NULL";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();


            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

            Row rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);

            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("NUMFICHA");
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("APELLIDO PATERNO");
            rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("APELLIDO MATERNO");
            rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("NOMBRE");
            rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("EXAMEN1");
            rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("EXAMEN2");

            int index = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(index);

                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getInt(1));
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue("");
                row.createCell(5).setCellValue("");
                index++;

            }


            ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            hwb.write(outByteStream);
            byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                               "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.flushBuffer();
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(outArray);
            outStream.flush();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your query does not return "weird" results? Maybe try to print whatever results the query returns

Comment: I am sure my query does not return any special simbols or characters, I tried to change to utf 8 but It does not work

Comment: please help, I am stuck in this

Comment: It's not weird symbols and characters you're seeing, it's just binary data being misinterpreted by Excel. Test your servlet (? or whatever it is) wih static data first, then add the database query.

Comment: I already test it , first I exported the excel file into a folder in my computer, in my computer the excel file It is ok, but in the above it is binary data not formatted

Comment: Even with static data my code generate excel with binary data, any more hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Excel files can receive text content, instead of printing out **binary** data, try printing out **text** data. If that doesn't resolve the issue, it should at least be able to point you in a better direction than printing binary data.

Comment: sorry I dont understand your answer how do I have do it?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not write directly from the workbook to the response outpustream:

```
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
...
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
hwb.write(outputStream);
....
```

So, try to skip the byte array (outpu stream) part, as that is likely to cause your problem.

Here's [some more info](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html?page=2) that may help.

Hope this gets you unstuck (or at least on the path to getting unstuck).

Comment: I get the same result, please help, any other ideas??

Comment: Even with static data I get the same result, any approach?

Comment: This may sound a bit weird, but this came to my mind: can you try reading the contents of the workbook into a temporary text file and then, from there, write that into the servlet response (using the response's writer)?

Comment: Ohh let me see I am checking that

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake if you are using certain servers. You have to reset the response before writing on it:

```
...
response.reset(); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                               "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");
...
```